# Analyzing URLs of Django app

Tags: django, nginx

In my Django app with a postgres backend, there exist public or private groups where users can post messages for each other. A public group may be represented by the url: `/group/49caad6b-6dbf-47eb-b5ce-335ac08d4ae6/public/`

Going over my nginx `access.log`, I sometimes see:

```
173.252.74.97 - - [04/Feb/2016:18:04:24 +0000] "GET /group/49caad6b-6dbf-47eb-b5ce-335ac08d4ae6/public/?_h=1&mse=AaE9BlxxTcQLY6k4n46RZ7VOzn98_RZH3-VuGyQbEpb3y66igoexzqhNJLIa557GLsdQNTVuVBcM3GyAsBzv0aJ7fla7TaSYpuFmLKQG3e7qLLEwXhy2hTOzU9F66Y37GwUbgt_RCWmxH2JFv8M0ezl-w_E9rZEWQirI9hhEC8_kd5LzafpcHShcVF4gbspu8cbh3VvssKEUtuyYybHupNaoRzx0H689PWpO6I9hxs6yvO-nF6mIA5vUVmKz3SPpXi8 HTTP/1.1" 200 11777
```

What is that appended with the URL? Is this malicious? If so, what should be my next step?

Comment: I can't say definitively but it just looks like some encoded info.

Comment: Does that url use any get parameters? `_h` and `mse` perhaps?

Comment: @Sayse: no, none whatsoever

Comment: I think that if you're not working with any `GET` param in your view, you don't have anything to worry about.

Comment: This isn't a signature of some kind of XSS attack eh?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The url you see has two get parameters appended to it

```
_h=1
mse=AaE9BlxxTc.......d5LzafpcHShcVF4gbsp....HupNaoRzx0...s6yvO-nF6mIA5vUVmKz3SPpXi8
```

(Cut down mse for brevity),

If I were to make a guess it would seem to me as though someone tried to either get hold of a message from the group or more likely test your group by trying to see if you allow users to use get requests to post data (in order to spam messages).

Do you have anything to worry about?

Not at the minute! Django is doing exactly what django does best and provides protection against these kind of bots/humans by making sure that you are using post requests where you need to.

I'd only start to worry about it when you suddenly find a spammer has won but I think you have plenty of time before that happens if this is all they're trying.

Comment: Disclaimer: I could be wrong, and this is just an educated guess at what this could be..